# Excel - Distritution of inventory in dock buffer management system. Simple

Tags: excel, performance, excel-formula, inventory, inventory-management

I will like to create a visual representation, like a bird view, of how we distribute our inventory in the dock. I have attach a photo to see what data I am working with and what I want to create, in a simplified way.

1st you scan the location of the buffer ("Mx1", "Mx2"..etc), then you scan all of the pallets in that location, up to 10, automatically gets the appointment tracker ("12345ABC", "12345XYZ"). Based on this tracker it will assign a colour code to each different one to be able to differentiate them visually.

Then it will transfer this information to the visual buffers. Not every buffer needs to be complete and different trackers can be in the same.  See photo to comprehend better.

I think a macro is not necessary, but what formulas will you use in order to create this? Specially to move the data to the buffers. [image: Example]

Thanks a lot!

I have tried excel formulas, but I cannot move the information correctly to the buffers

Comment: Can you try to express your problem in more general terms and use excel related terminology rather than industry specific one? I.e., which cells and ranges do you want to behave in which way and what have you already tried?

Comment: A couple of things.  (a) This is easier to solve with Excel O365, are you an O365 customer?  (b) Is there a fixed number of buffers/MXes?  An automatically varying number of buffers complicates this.  (c) The way I would solve this problem would mean not easily having the appointment tracker text vertically inside the colored buffers.  (d) Is the appointment tracker code in cell C11 above incorrect?

Comment: It is possible using formulas, if you are using `MS365` but if you want to merge cells based on total number of counts that requires `VBA` you cannot use a formula to merge cells or based on counts of cells you cant merge unless using `VBA`